# Swift present viewController issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a ViewController that I present like this:

```
guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendarViewController") as? FSCalendarViewController else {return}
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

Is there any way I can present it modally so I can swipe to close the presented vc without making the previous VC smaller? I feel like most big apps are using that functionality.

Comment: Usually it is not common to dismiss a screen that was presented with a full screen presentation style,  with a gesture. They usually have a button added to dismiss it.
Do you want it full screen and dismiss it with a swipe?

Comment: Yes, I should have given more information, my bad. The main view in the presented viewController have clear background, and a view in it that only takes up half the screen, from bottom to the middle, so when I present the ViewController I still see my VC behind. 
I would prefer to present it modally if I could avoid the VC behind getting smaller.

Comment: What if you set the `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` instead ? This will remove the swipe to dismiss gesture which you will need to add using a gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext